# Frontend editor with save image uploading methods

Tags: front-end, editor, jce, tinymce

I am trying to build a forum where users are allowed to upload and insert image into their posts. Surprisingly, this is not as easy as it seems.

TinyMCE when used on frontend doesn't have the "insert image" button. I tried JCE as well, but once you click the "image" button, you will see the filesystem on my server, you definitely don't want a random user to be able to see that. The normal behavior of inserting an image into a forum post should be like this: right after being uploaded, the image should appear in the post, and the user don't and shouldn't have to worry about which folder to put the image. Is there any setting in JCE tha can help achieve this? Or is there any other editor that can do this?

Comment: The Kunena forum component already has this functionality, using drag and drop. Is there any reason you're building your own, rather than using an existing extension?

Comment: I am using easydiscuss, the build-in BBCode editor of which is quite outdated

Answer (score 2):

Latest releases of Easy Discuss actually offers this feature. Once you upload the image you can insert anywhere in your message.

Also if you want to keep using JCE, you may just configure the filesystem options for your users JCE profile to only allow access to a specific directory tied with your users' id.